# How does the promise api works?

Tags: javascript

```js
function fakeApi() {
     return new Promise((reslove,reject)=>{
         var x =0
         setTimeout(() => {
            const data =[
              {a:"a",price:200},
              {a:"b",price:400},
              {a:"c",price:100}
            ]
            if(x==0){
              reslove(data) 
            }else{

              reject("aaa")
            }
         }, 1);

     })
}

fakeApi()
.then(console.log)
```

how does the data variable is getting into the console.log  with using console.log (data)?
does it added by then function ?

Comment: Please indent properly your code, it is really painful to read it as it is.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: then takes callback and that callback will have first parameter which you pass in resolve, so in your case console.log is taken as a callback function and as @sjahan said please read the documentation

Comment: Tnx  Abhay Sehgal